# Conditional formatStyle in DT

Tags: r, dt, htmlwidgets

I want to color rows in column A by values in column B.

The code below is based on the example from the vignette [Link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html), but shows only the condition for two columns: mobile_number by mobile_flag.

Data:

```
head(test[, c("EMBG","mobile_number", "home_number",  "mobile_flag", "home_number_flag")])
          EMBG mobile_number      home_number mobile_flag
1 101001455126   075-201-543      02/2446-275     correct
2 101010455015   55555555555      55555555555   incorrect
3 101014455095             0                0   incorrect
4 101947455134   075/482-356      02/2460-020     correct
5 101952450264  070 22 16 18 ----------------     correct
6 101953450012             0      02/2446-276   incorrect
  home_number_flag
1          correct
2        incorrect
3        incorrect
4          correct
5        incorrect
6          correct
```

My DT table:

```
> datatable(test) %>% formatStyle(
+   'mobile_number', 'mobile_flag',
+   backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("correct", "incorrect"), c('green', 'red')))
```

However, I want to simultaniouslly color both mobile_number and home_number, based on home_number_flag and mobile_flag, respectivly.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
library(DT)
datatable(test) %>%
    formatStyle(
        columns = c("mobile_number", "home_number"),
        valueColumns = c("mobile_flag", "home_number_flag"),
        backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("correct", "incorrect"), 
                                     c("green", "red"))
    )
```

`columns` specifies which columns you would like to conditionally format. `valueColumns` specifies which columns should be evaluated using the conditions specified in `styleEqual` of `backgroundColor`.

Note that order in `columns` corresponds with order in `valueColumns` (e.g "mobile_number" is conditionally colored by "mobile_flag").